# Produce the following output (for and while loops) in python?

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I have an assignment about for and while loops and I am just confused with some stuff. It would be much appreciated if you guys can help me.

The question is produce the following out using for and while loops in python:

```
1
FredFredFredFred
2
FredFredFred
3
FredFred
4
Fred
```

this is what I have so far for a "for loop"

```
for i in range(1,5):
    print(i)
    print('Fred'*i)
```

but I can't get the 'Fred' to be like what they asked us for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Printing `Fred` one lest time each iteration can be controlled by multiplying the string by a decreasing value (in this case, `5-i`).

```
for i in range(1,5):
     print(i)
     print("Fred"*(5-i))
```

This outputs:

```
1
FredFredFredFred
2
FredFredFred
3
FredFred
4
Fred
```

Comment: In that case, would you mind marking the question as accepted?  I'm happy I could help you.

Comment: Wow, someone got a spare 500 reps for this answer

Answer (score 1):

Using While loop

```
i = 1
while (i < 5):
   print(i)
   print('fred'*(5-i))
   i = i + 1
```

Output:

```
1
fredfredfredfred
2
fredfredfred
3
fredfred
4
fred
```